# Cannot change to Unity 3D!

Tags: unity, updates, launcher

Major problem here and I'd appreciate some help!

I was installing WINE and Steam to get my games running. Got everything installed and configured, and my games were working. However after that, the Update Manager popped up to say that I needed to update my system. I ran the updates, and then the cogwheel in the corner of the screen turned red, because I needed to reboot. I rebooted, and now I cannot change the size of my Unity Launcher, and none of my WINE applications will run!!

I logged out and actually selected Ubuntu 3D from the login menu, then logged in again, but I STILL cannot change the size of my launcher, and my WINE apps will not work! I even tried CCSM and changed the size manually, but it didn't work. Also noticing that when I click on Dash it takes a long time to actually open, which it wasn't doing before.

If it helps I now have two extra options when I choose Ubuntu 3D - I have "Gnome Classic" and "Gnome Classic (no effects)", but where these came from I have no idea.

What the hell have I done to mess up my system? :-(

Someone please help me because I am seriously just considering a reinstall of Ubuntu which I don't want to do!

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to reinstall the AMD Catalyst driver!